# How to fork a process from kernel space in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, header, kernel, fork

I asked this question at Unix&Linux, and they told me to ask it here.

I need to use a function with the same functionality as the`fork` system call.
It's my understanding that forking a process from kernel space would involve calling `do_fork`, but I can't figure out how I would do that. It's defined in `fork.c`, and since it's not a header file, I can't include it, can I? Please help!

Edit: The reason I need to `fork` from the kernel is for an experiment to test the reasource use of a [delta queue](https://wiki.osdev.org/Blocking_Process), a type of queue for sleeping processes that sleep for a known amount of time (ex. 5 milliseconds). The reason I want to simulate it and not code an actual delta queue is because I don't have the experience/knowledge to do it. For my simulation I made a system call that runs like a delta queue would, but to test it I need processes to put to sleep. Using `fork` would be the easiest way for me to make a lot of processes for the test (easier than using `kthreads`), but since I plan to run this experiment in kernel space I can't just run the system call. I could run it in user space, but then that adds an extra layer of abstraction that real delta queue wouldn't have, as it would be run by the kernel. That would minimize the relevancy of my experiement.

Comment: Would you mind telling us your [X problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? Because I struggle to think what kind of problem forking a user process from the kernel would solve. Or why you're working in kernel space in the first place. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, please give more information. Generally do_fork is used by the kernel to handle the creation of a process in response to a syscall. If you are in kernel space, you can look at kthread_create.

Comment: I doubt you need to simulate this into kernel there is a lot of possibilities in user space... Create client/server model server managing the delta queue and clients using an API (date_sleep()), pipes and signals can help you very easily.